# How to set "SQL Server Compatible Syntax" property on MDB file via Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ms-access

Access Database has a property called "SQL Server Compatible Syntax" (in Ms Access 2003-, it's in Tools -> Tables/Views -> SQL Server Compatible Syntax; in Access 2007+, it's in Office Logo -> Access Options -> OBJECT DESIGNERS -> QUERY DESIGN).

How can I set this option via Delphi? (ADO, ADOX or any other way...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify these property you must use the `Microsoft Office Access database engine Object Library`. From Delphi you can import this library using the option Components ->Import Component -> Import Type Library .

Try this sample.

```
uses
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  DAO_TLB in '..\12.0\Imports\DAO_TLB.pas';


procedure test;
var
  LEngine : _DBEngine;
  LDataBase : Database;
begin
  LEngine:=CoDbEngine.Create as _DBEngine;
  //Open the access database
  LEngine.OpenDatabase('C:\Foo\Bar.accdb', dbDriverNoPrompt, false, '');
  LDataBase:=LEngine.Workspaces.Item[0].Databases.Item[0];
  LDataBase.Properties.Item['ANSI Query Mode'].Value := 1;
  Writeln('Done');
  LDataBase.Close();
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Test;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will almost certainly need to use DAO to make the change. The following C# code does it, but unfortunately I can't offer actual Delphi code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;

namespace daoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // COM reference required:
            //     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
            var dbe = new DBEngine();
            dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.mdb");
            Database db = dbe.Workspaces[0].Databases[0];
            try
            {
                db.Properties["ANSI Query Mode"].Value = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("ANSI Query Mode has been enabled for this database.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```